# PhpMyAdmin no logra hacer DROP de una Primary Key en una tabla nueva y vacía - MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

al grano...
Acabo de crear una tabla y asigné una PK, la cuál me di cuenta que no era la que iba a asignar.

Luego de terminar la creación de columnas, procedo a eliminar la PK por medio de Phpmyadmin, y obtengo el siguiente error.

> #1075 - Puede ser solamente un campo automatico y este debe ser definido como una clave

Dejo un gif del proceso para su visualicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo, que deberías de cambiar el AUTO_INCREMENT a otro, guardarlo y luego intentar eliminar

Comment: entonces, el indice, sería un campo de tipo indice.

Comment: Formatear puede solucionar todo XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te deja porque el campo es auto_increment, estos campos tienen que ser primary key, así que antes tienes que cambiar el campo y quitarle el auto_increment:

```
ALTER TABLE `equipos` CHANGE `indice` `indice` INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

Y luego ya puedes retirar la key:

```
ALTER TABLE `equipos` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Pero puede que lo que te venga mejor sea mantener la PRIMARY KEY con AUTO_INCREMENT sobre el campo indice, y crear una UNIQUE KEY sobre el campo que querías usar como PRIMARY KEY, que me imagino que es clave:

```
ALTER TABLE `equipos` ADD UNIQUE KEY `clave` (clave);
```

Comment: Si o si debo realizar 2 pasos... mi idea era dejar el auto_increment como indice, no como pk.

Comment: Creo que quieres usar clave como PK. Yo en estos casos mantengo el campo id (o indice en tu caso) como PK y AUTO_INCREMENT, y el campo clave lo pongo como UNIQUE KEY.

Comment: gracias por el consejo